# Can nova support multiple hypervisor on a single controller?

Tags: openstack-nova

In `nova.conf`, we need to specify `computer_driver` to either `kvm` or `xen`. Dose that mean one nova controller can support only one hypervisor technology? Can I mix `kvm` and `xen` virtual machines in the same cloud?

Answer (score 2):

You can mix hypervisors, but on different compute nodes within a cell. You can then use image properties or scheduler hints to make sure vm's based on certain images land on the hypervisor type that they support or to schedule directly to a hypervisor type.